# Not able to commit the code with the verify committer hook

Tags: github, bitbucket-server

I am unable to Push Commits in Browse GTT EEE shared / xmas_config - Bitbucket due to Verify committer hook. I have double checked my Name & Email ID in local GIT Commit, Bitbucket and Microsoft Outlook. The Verify Committer hook has to be temporarily being disabled for working.

Also, I already have access to the Project/ Repository-

I was able to Commit my changes/work, but not Push to Bitbucket. And, after the Verify Committer hook was temporarily disabled by Admin, I was able to Push my commits on Repository.

I have tried with the hook is disabled and it is working but when the hook is enable I cant able to push my commits. Also checked with the admin but not working any changes. Is there any solution for it.